# Node_modules não é reconhecido

Tags: node.js

Porque acontece isso no prompt do Windows 10?
Comandos como no nomedoarquivo.js funciona.

Isso acontece quando eu tento:

```
node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

Nas variáveis de ambiente coloquei:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Já tentei com o nome de usuário, com `C:`, nada funcionou. O módulo do mocha não foi instalado global, está em outra pasta `node_modules` dentro da pasta do projeto, coloquei também esse caminho no PATH e nada.

Como funciona isso de `node_modules`, instalação global, local e como isso se aplica no Windows com variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo! Podes dar um exemplo do código onde estás a usar o `mocha`? Normalmente fazes `npm install mocha` eventualmente com `-save` ou `-save-dev`.

Comment: Olá eu descobri o problema precisava colocar node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha, para funcionar, obrigada.

Comment: Tinhas feito `npm install -g mocha`?

Comment: Sim, o problema é que eu estava seguindo um tutorial que usa Mac e tem umas divergências de comandos, passei por isso várias vezes. No Mac não precisa digitar node antes do caminho (path - node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha).

Comment: E juntaste o caminho na PATH do windows?

Comment: Não já estava certo o path, mas ele só reconheceu o comando com a palavra "node" antes do comando node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.

Answer (score 1):

O comando é de uma aula de node e na aula o professor usa Mac e na aula era só instalar o mocha e depois digitar essa linha de comando, mas no PC que é o meu caso (Windows) ele não aceita o comando sem a palavra "node" na frente, até voltei a aula várias vezes, mas o professor que utiliza Mac não digita "node" e no Windows funcionou dessa forma:

```
node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

Só digitando:

```
node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

Causa o erro "Node_modules não é reconhecido", que foi o porque de eu pedir ajuda aqui no fórum.
Respondi, porque vi que uma pessoa comentou e se alguém tiver esse erro aqui está a resposta.

(Resposta editada por causa de pontos negativos, não sabia que tinha que escrever uma resposta comprida)

Comment: Explica melhor a resposta para outros perceberem melhor. Assim tão curto chama votos negativos...